# How to make a Object.map?

Tags: react-native

I had an array of data. 7 items for which I used data.map. I loaded this array on firease and now I can't call it like this . Because this is not the Array is already in the Objects.

Question.

How do I do data.map for Objects. Moreover, I need to transfer data. Specifically: id, name , info , latlng. Inside is the ImageCard that should be in the data.map.

Example object:

```
Object {
  "0": Object {
    "id": 0,
    "image": "/images/Stargate.jpg",
    "info": "Stargate is a 1994 science fiction adventure film released through Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM) and Carolco Pictures..",
    "latlng": Object {
      "latitude": 53.6937,
      "longitude": -336.1968,
    },
    "name": "Stargate",
    "year": "1994",
  },
```

Comment: Multiple ways: `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, `Object.entries` are all the possible options to transform Object into an Array matter

Answer (score 1):

You can extract keys from Object using `Object.keys` which will return an array of all keys and then map this array.

like this,

```
 const obj={
    "id": 0,
    "image": "/images/Stargate.jpg",
    "info": "Stargate is a 1994 science fiction adventure film released through Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM) and Carolco Pictures..",
    "latlng": Object {
      "latitude": 53.6937,
      "longitude": -336.1968,
    },
    "name": "Stargate",
    "year": "1994",
  }

  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.map(item=>{
    //..... do your stuff from object like,
  let y=obj[item]
   //  or whatever
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do that
one mentioned by Jaydeep Galani

another approach would be to use Proxy

```
const obj={
"id": 0,
"image": "/images/Stargate.jpg",
"info": "Stargate is a 1994 science fiction adventure film released through 
   Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM) and Carolco Pictures..",
"latlng": Object {
  "latitude": 53.6937,
  "longitude": -336.1968,
},
"name": "Stargate",
"year": "1994",
}
 const newObj = new Proxy(obj,{
 get: (target, prop)=>{
  let newArr = [];
  if(prop === 'map'){
   // then first convert target into array 
   Object.keys(target).foreach(item => {
     newArr.push({item:target[item]})
     })


   // then apply map function to that and return the result
    return newArr.map((item)=>{
   //your code goes here like
   return<div>{item.info}</div>
    })

    }
   }

  })
```